# Assign data from 3 UItextfields into 3 different strings

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I am trying to get 3 different values from 3 different Uitextfields and then save them into 1 string to send it to a rest API server through a button action. I am stucked on how to get all 3 texts inputs from the 3 UItextfields.Any thought? My textfields are account,username,password.

```
UITextField *account = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 50, 140, 30)];
account.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
account.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
account.placeholder = @"Account";
account.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
account.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
account.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
account.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
account.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
account.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:account];
[account release];


UITextField *username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 80, 140, 30)];
username.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
username.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
username.placeholder = @"User ID";
username.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
username.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
username.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
username.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
username.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
username.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:username];
[username release];

UITextField *password = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90, 110, 140, 30)];
password.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
password.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
password.placeholder = @"Password";
password.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
password.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
password.secureTextEntry = YES;
password.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
password.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
password.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
password.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:password];
[password release];
```

Can't find away to get all 3 datas when using the :

```
 -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set textfield tag

```
    userNameTextField.tag = 1
    accountTextField.tag = 2
    passwordTextField.tag = 3
```

Save the values in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

        switch (textField.tag) {
            case 1:
                //userNameTextField
                NSString *userNameTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
                //save
                break;
            case 2:
                //accountTextField
                NSString *accountTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
                //save
                break;  
            case 3:
                //passwordTextField
                NSString *passwordTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textField.text,string];
                //save
                break;  
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Got a mini problem still. After applying your method or even a new of mine which invovles this code :
    
    -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
        switch (textField.tag) {
            case 1:
                string1 = textField.text;
                break;
            case 2:
                string2 = textField.text;
                break;
            case 3:
                string3 = textField.text;
                break;
            
             default:
                break;
    }
}
I get the values only of the account and the username..Any thoughts?

Comment: Neverming i found it was a small bug :) Thanks a lot everyone for your help in this!!!

Answer (score 0):

you should keep the UITextFields as ivars, as well as correlating NSStrings (userNameString, passwordString, accountString). then on the following method you should check which textField invoked your delegate and assign the textField's text to the correct string. you can also use the textfield tag property to differentiate between them, and then you don't need to keep them as ivars..

```
   -(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField==userName)
       userNameString = textField.text;
    if (textField== account)
       accountString = textField.text
    if (textField== password)
       password String = textField.text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. give each text field a `tag`, e.g. `1`, `2` and `3`
2. in `textFieldDidEndEditing:` distinguish the three text fields by tag:

.

```
if (textField.tag == 1) {
   // assign the text to the right variable
}
... etc.
```

If you follow this pattern, you can avoid cluttering your class with many properties.

To make the code more readable, you can use this pattern:

```
#define userNameTextField 1
#define accountTextField 2
#define passwordTextField 3
```

or

```
typedef enum { 
   userNameTextField = 1,
   accountTextField,
   passwordTextField
} TextFields;
```

Comment: how do i give a tag to a textfield if it's not in a cell table?

Comment: When you set it up: `textField.tag = userNameTextField;` (or `1`)